# Read filenames in chunks in Java streams from a folder

Tags: java, file, arraylist, heap-memory, file-read

I have a directory with millions of files in it. I want to read the filenames into an ArrayList. If I read all filenames into an ArrayList, it consumes more memory. I suspect if a huge number of files are present in the directory, Java might throw heap space error.
Is there a way to read files in a directory in chunks/batches, Say 5 filenames each time.

Comment: i'm not sure as i don't have a directory with millions of files. But maybe you can use a stream? Like for instance Arrays.stream(Paths.get("path/to/file").toFile().list()); You can than use the StringStream to do the things you wanted to do with the fileNames

Comment: Even If I use code like **Arrays.stream(Paths.get("path/to/file").toFile().list());**, This part **Paths.get("path/to/file").toFile().list()** will still bring all the filenames into memory. My problem is to use less memory to get all filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [Path.list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) for this, it will return you a stream which is a lazy evaluated:

```
List<String> fileNames = Path.list("path_to_directory")
                             .map(Path::getFileName)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The files will be processed one by one and this will consume less memory. However you still might get memory issues if the final list `fileNames` will get too big.  So the terminal (collect) operation in the stream pipeline might cause some issues.

But for example if you process the filename directly on the stream (using forEach for example without collecting them) you can avoid loading all the names into the memory.

```
Path.list("path_to_directory")
    .map(Path::getFileName)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

// print files one by one without loading all of them at the same time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This will also load all the filenames into **fileNames** . I need to have only a subset of filenames from a folder in the memory. Say if there was 100 files in a folder, i need only 5 files in the memory. After I print the 5 filenames, I should get the next 5 filenames and print them. **The objective is to use less memory by not loading all filenames in memory**

Comment: @Nishanth if you will not use collect, but print the filenames directory you can avoid loading all of them into the memory. Please see second part of my answer. What exactly do you need to do with the filenames? Just print them?

Comment: No Mr.Anton Balaniuc, I need a chunk of filenames to be streamed from the folder. If I get filenames one by one, it consumes more time. Getting filenames in chunks will be faster. For Example: f there are 100 files in a folder, and if I print them one by one, it consumes more time. Rather printing 10 filenames at a time will consume less amount of time. Instead of using "forEach" is there any possible way to process like ".forEachChunkOfSize(10)" ?

Comment: @Nishanth, there is no such possibility with streams. By nature stream process elements one by one.  But you can do this in parallel: `Path.list("path_to_directory").parallel()` will convert stream into a `parallelStream`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) class to traverse and read one file at a time. In this way you will not get OOM error.

Use [Files.html#walkFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)) method to visit files in directory.

General example is below.

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\path\\with\\lots\\of\\files");
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            // here you have the files to process
            System.out.println(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
           return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
          return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

Here is link to [Java SE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).
For more examples, refer [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.nio.file.Files&method=walkFileTree).